# paypal button customer field php variable

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-buttons

I have implemented a paypal button on my webiste in order to buy premium membership. So to know (in IPN listener) who payed i'm sending the costumer variable to paypal...anyway code (on server side) looks like:

```html
<?php 
session_start();
$email = $_SESSION['email']; // example@t-online.de
echo $email;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
  <title>Registrierung</title> 
</head> 
<body>
 



<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="FGAB5Z3G63VSL">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$email;?>">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form



</body>
</html>
```

on ipn side i receive "<'?= $email;?> as the costumer variable (without the ' after the < )....not example@t-online.de